# Storing Database Passwords in a Database

Tags: php, mysql, security, passwords

We are building a system that will have multiple separate client databases, clients are allowed to create as much as they want.  There is an "Admin" database that holds the usernames, the database names, usernames and passwords for the databases on the server are all stored in an "admin" database.  I use the information to connect to the database selected by the user, so I need to be able to be able to retrieve the actual password (I think... right?).

So what is the best way to go about storing the passwords and even the database names?  Is there a way I can encrypt, then unencrypt when I need it?

Thanks in advance for any help..

Aloha,

James

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encrypt the database name, you can use functions like [AES_ENCRYPT()/AES_DECRYPT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt).

You NEVER store passwords in plain.

You NEVER store passwords in decryptable form.

You store the password using one-way encryption. To check a password, you encrypt the password the user gave you and compare it to what you stored.

For MySQL, you'd use the [PASSWORD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function.

Comment: "NEVER" is a pretty strong word.  In this case, he actually needs to store the passwords.  Not to check that they are correct when somebody types them in, but to use to connect to other services.

Comment: Actually he could still store the password hashed and compare hashes and just use the password that user typed in, temporarily stored (encrypted) for connecting to the services. Never is a strong word, no doubt, but you also have to be careful not to assume you do need to store the password in reversible form just because you need to use it once in a while.

Comment: Of course, it the user's site needs to maintain a constant DB connection, even when he is not logged in, then that is a case where you would need to store the password in a datasource connection (whatever is appropriate for the environment) just like you would for any other DB password.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the deal with storing passwords, which is really the most important part of all of this:

1. Plain text is a big no-no, because if your server is ever compromised, an attacker can release a list of all of your client's usernames and passwords, which is bad for all sorts of reasons.
2. Encrypted passwords are bad because if your server is ever compromised, an attacker can simply decrypt the passwords the same way as your program did, and now you have the same problem as plaintext.
3. Cryptographic digests like MD5, SHA-1, and even SHA-512 are a lot better because you only ever store and compare the hashed passwords, but they are still bad because they were designed to hash data very quickly for the purposes of data integrity and signing.  This makes it surprisingly easy to reverse-engineer passwords via brute force attacks on modern hardware--even with salt! (See articles on leveraging GPUs for this purpose!)

So where does this leave us?  It turns out that digests are a good way to go, but you want ones that are computationally complex so that brute force attacks are difficult.  There are a number of these available, but I have adopted the [Brcypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) hash in my professional work.

As a side note, passwords should *always* be stored with salt to avoid rainbow table attacks.  One advantage of Bcrypt is that is has the salting routines built into it, so that you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score -1):

I would second the NEVER store passwords in plain/decryptable form.

If you really need to access the users databases, you could use an admin/root with access to any user-database in the server.